# @click handler does not work in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

.vue component

```
<template>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                Загрузка файлов
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type='file' multiple='multiple' class='form-control' @change='changed'>

                <div v-for='file in files'>
                    {{ file.name }} {{ formatSize(file.size) }}
                </div>
                <div class='alert alert-danger' v-if='error.files' v-for='err in error.files'>
                    {{ err }}
                </div>
                <div class='alert alert-danger' v-if='failed.length' v-for='f in failed'>
                    Не удалось загрузить: {{ f }}
                </div>
                <template v-if='saved.length' v-for='f, index in saved'>
                    <div class='alert alert-info'>
                        {{ f.original_filename }}
                        <a href='#' class='badge badge-info pull-right' @click.native='delete(f, index)' title='Удалить'>
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x" v-if='f.isDeleting'></i>
                            <i class='fa fa-close' v-else></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='alert alert-danger' v-if='f.isError'>
                        {{ f.isError }}
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' @click='handleOk' v-if='saved.length && !isUploading'>
                    Ок
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="handleUpload">
                    <template v-if='isUploading'>
                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x"></i>
                    </template>
                    <template v-else>
                        Загрузить
                    </template>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="handleCancel">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</template>
<script>
export default {

    props: {
        propShow: {
            required: true,
            type: Boolean
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            files: [],
            saved: [],
            failed: [],
            isUploading: false,
            modal: null,
            input: null,
            error: {},
        }
    },

    watch: {
        propShow: function(val, oldVal) {
            if(val) {
                this.modal.show('modal');
            } else {
                this.modal.hide('modal');
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.modal = $(this.$el);
        this.input = this.modal.find('input[type=file]');
    },

    methods: {
        changed(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            this.files = files;
        },

        delete(f, index) {
            f.isDeleting = true;
            delete f.isError;
            this.$set(this.saved, index, f);
            this.doPostRequest('/file/' + f.id + '/delete', {}, (body) => {
                f.isDeleting = false;
                if(body.ok) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < this.saved.length; i++) {
                        if( this.saved[i].id === f.id ) {
                            this.saved.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    f.isError = body.data.error;
                    this.$set(this.saved, index, f);
                }
            }, (body) => {
                f.isDeleting = false;
            });
        },

        handleOk() {
            if( this.isUploading ) return;
            this.$emit('ok', this.saved);
            this.saved = [];
            this.failed = [];
        },

        handleUpload() {
            if( this.isUploading ) return;
            this.isUploading = true;
            let data = new FormData();
            for(let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                data.append('files[]', this.files[i]);
            }
            this.error = {};
            this.doPostRequest('/file/upload', data, (body) => {
                if(body.ok) {
                    this.saved.push.apply(this.saved, body.data.saved);
                    this.failed.push.apply(this.failed, body.data.failed);
                    this.files = [];
                    this.input.val('');
                } else {
                    this.error = body.data;
                }
                this.isUploading = false;
            }, (body) => {
                this.isUploading = false;
            });
        },

        handleCancel() {
            if( this.isUploading ) return;
            this.files = [];
            this.input.val('');
            this.failed = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < this.saved.length; i++) {
                this.delete(this.saved[i], i);
            }
            this.saved = [];
            this.$emit('cancel');
        },

        formatSize(size) {
            if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
                return (size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' TB';
            } else if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
                return (size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
            } else if (size > 1024 * 1024) {
                return (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
            } else if (size > 1024) {
                return (size / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
            }
            return size.toString() + ' B';
        }
    }

}
```

When I click on '.fa-close' link (this part below) - it must call `delete` method, but it does not.

```
                    <div class='alert alert-info'>
                    {{ f.original_filename }}
                    <a href='#' class='badge badge-info pull-right' @click.native='delete(f, index)' title='Удалить'>
                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x" v-if='f.isDeleting'></i>
                        <i class='fa fa-close' v-else></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

In chrome developer tools I see that this event handler is attached to this link.

Comment: anything in console?

Comment: put it together in JSFiddle to make us able to help

Comment: The problem was: my method was named after js reserved word `delete`

Comment: If the issue is resolved, you may answer your own question and mark it as fixed. This will help others who may have similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: my method was named after js reserved word delete